# Deserialize Facebook API Response

Tags: json, facebook, api, serialization, response

I created a vb-programm that sends a Facebook-API request and deserializes it into an object I created by using this:

```
Dim PostList As JsonPostList = Deserializer.Deserialize(Of JsonPostList)(LoadJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/" & Params("Userid") & "/feed?fields=id,message,type,actions,picture,link,created_time&limit=30&access_token=" + ACCESSTOKEN))
```

This was working great until yesterday. Today in the morning the code above returned "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Did something in the Facebook Response change?

LoadJsonFromUrl does not more than converting the Response to a String:

```
Private Function LoadJsonFromUrl(Url As String) As String

    Dim Text As String = ""

    ' --- Request --- '
    Dim Uri As Uri = New Uri(Url)
    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(Uri), HttpWebRequest)
    Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    Request.Timeout = 30000

    ' --- Response --- '
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Response.CharacterSet)

    ' --- Stream --- '
    Using Stream As IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()

        Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream, Encoding)
            Text = String.Copy(Reader.ReadToEnd())
        End Using

    End Using

    Response.Close()

    Logger.Write(Text, Logger.MessageType.Info)
    ' Return
    Return Text

End Function
```

My Classes:

```
Public Class JsonPostList

    Public data As List(Of JsonPostData)
    Public pageing As JsonPaging

End Class

Public Class JsonPostData

    Public id As String
    Public message As String
    Public type As String
    Public actions As String
    Public picture As String
    Public link As String
    Public created_time As String

End Class

Public Class JsonPaging

    Public [next] As String
    Public [previous] As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently on the facebook api "actions" into an Array. I excluded actions and it works fine now.